# Django's Image Field and Google app engine

Tags: django, google-cloud-platform

I have a `django` app deployed on google cloud platform.
I also have the same app deployed on heroku (It works fine).
I have a model in my code that looks like this :

```
class Notification(models.Model):
## other fields 
qrcode = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
```

When I pass this model to the serializer, I got a status code 500.

I googled it and find some answers referring to `PIL` library or some needed configuration in the Google Cloud App Engine in order to support `ImageField`.

**NOTE** :

`django-admin` on heroku looks like this:

[image: Django-admin on heroku]

`django-admin` on google cloud looks like this :

[image: Django-admin on google cloud]

Does anyone know what to do in this case?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: from what I understand to your situation is you need to install or update your PIL so you can use ImageField. Google has a [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27) regarding using PIL to your App Engine.

Comment: Thnx for the anwser. It seems like I should create a bucket for my project on google cloud...etc.

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Platform has a [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27) on how you can use Python libraries on Google App Engine.